# java.sql.SQLDataException: ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string (Oracle)

Tags: oracle, date

I'm trying to run a script through Java code

```
query.append("SELECT CNAME,CREATEDATE  FROM MERGE_DATA_VW \r\n" + 
       "WHERE TO_DATE(CREATEDATE, 'DD-MM-RR') = TO_DATE('26-NOV-19', 'DD-MM-RR')\";");
stmt = con.prepareStatement(query.toString());
rs = stmt.executeQuery();
```

When trying to run the script in Oracle SQL Developer it works fine, but when running my java code it gives an SQLDataException:

```
java.sql.SQLDataException: ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input   string

at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:440)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:396)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:837)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:445)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:191)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:523)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:207)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:863)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:1153)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1275)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3576)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3620)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1491)
```

I can't find whats causing the error, please anyone? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don' think you need `TO_DATE` for `CREATEDATE` as it is already a date.

Also, your `TO_DATE('26-NOV-19', 'DD-MM-RR')` should be `TO_DATE('26-NOV-19', 'DD-MON-RR')`

Try this:

```
SELECT
    CNAME,
    CREATEDATE
FROM
    MERGE_DATA_VW
WHERE
    TRUNC(CREATEDATE) = TO_DATE('26-NOV-19', 'DD-MON-RR');
```

Cheers!!

Comment: Actually it should be `to_date('26-NOV-2019', 'DD-MON-YYYY')`. It is now the year **2020** and there is no excuse for still using a pre-Millennial workaround for the Y2K bug. Or just use an ASCII date literal `date '2019-11-26'`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `CREATEDATE` is a column of the `DATE` data type then you do not need to use `TO_DATE` on it (as it is already a `DATE`), you also do not need the trailing `\";`.

You could also use a date literal.

So assuming that `CREATEDATE` always has a mignight time component:

```java
query.append("SELECT CNAME,CREATEDATE  FROM MERGE_DATA_VW \r\n" + 
       "WHERE CREATEDATE = DATE '2019-11-26'");
```

If your `CREATEDATE` column has a non-midnight time component then you need to compare on a range (or use `TRUNC` but that would not allow you to use an index on the column and would require a separate function-based index):

```java
query.append("SELECT CNAME,CREATEDATE  FROM MERGE_DATA_VW \r\n" + 
       "WHERE CREATEDATE >= DATE '2019-11-26' AND CREATEDATE < DATE '2019-11-27'");
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrong date format

```
TO_DATE('26-NOV-19', 'DD-MM-RR')
```

Please user Correct date

```
ie 'DD-MON-RR' FOR '26-NOV-19'
```

Answer (score -1):

You where caluse should look like -

```
WHERE TO_DATE(CREATEDATE, 'DD-MM-RR') = TO_DATE('26-11-19', 'DD-MM-RR')
```